# Java ArrayList Total Count

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a requirement where I need to loop through List of Java objects and adding to ArrayList. Its giving the individual count of Java objects correctly, but not the final count of all objects. Not sure where I am doing mistake. This is the output. The expected should be 5945. Please help me resolving the issue.

I tried declaring the list as a static global variable, but still getting the same issue.

```
categoryEntryList --------->10
categoryEntryList --------->12
categoryEntryList --------->53
categoryEntryList --------->2
categoryEntryList --------->35
categoryEntryList --------->79
categoryEntryList --------->4355
categoryEntryList --------->1
All Category Entries size ------->692
```

This is the code:

```
private static List<CategoryEntry> getCategoryMedia(
        List<Category> categoryList) throws KalturaApiException,
        ParseException {
    int index = 1;
    List<CategoryEntry> categoryEntries = new ArrayList<CategoryEntry>();
    List<CategoryEntry> finalEntries = new ArrayList<CategoryEntry>();
    for (Category category : categoryList) {
        CategoryEntryFilter filter = new CategoryEntryFilter();
        FilterPager pager = new FilterPager();
        pager.pageIndex = index;
        pager.pageSize = 500;
        filter.categoryIdEqual = category.id;
        filter.statusEqual = CategoryEntryStatus.ACTIVE;
        CategoryEntryListResponse categoryEntryList = getCategoryEntry(filter, pager);
        if (categoryEntryList.totalCount != 0) {
            System.out.println("categoryEntryList --------->"+categoryEntryList.totalCount);
            for (CategoryEntry entry : categoryEntryList.objects) {
                if (entry != null) {
                    categoryEntries.add(entry);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    index ++;
    finalEntries.addAll(categoryEntries);
    //System.out.println("Total Media ------- >"
    //+ finalEntries.size());
    return finalEntries;
}

protected static CategoryEntryListResponse getCategoryEntry(
        CategoryEntryFilter filter, FilterPager pager)
        throws KalturaApiException {
    CategoryEntryService categoryEntryService = client
            .getCategoryEntryService();
    CategoryEntryListResponse categoryEntryList = categoryEntryService
            .list(filter, pager);
    return categoryEntryList;
}
```

Thanks,
Rajyalakshmi S

Comment: You have a condition `if (entry != null)`, are you sure all the entries are different of `null`

Comment: You've commented it out, but you're printing out the size of `finalEntries`... we have no idea how that relates to the `totalCount` in each `CategoryEntryListResponse`...

Comment: can't find `All Category Entries size ------->692 ` in code  - where's that?

Comment: This is where the debugger would be really helpful as the solution is likely to depending on what data you are passing in which we cannot see.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet - I commented to test out something. But totalcount and finalentries count is same value.

Comment: @ Jan - This print statement is in the calling method of getCategoryMedia.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently some of the elements are `null` and are not added to the final list due to the condition. This may be related to the `list(...)` implementation and/or `CategoryFilter filter` for both we didn't see the source code.

Comment: @ Zbynek - You mean the if conditions need to removed so that it will work. Not getting your answer.

Comment: I'm saying the `if` is causing the difference. I cannot tell whether it's good idea to remove it, probably there is reason to exclude `null` items.

Answer (score 0):

you should keep a running tally

```
int tally = 0; //declare and assign tally
for (Category category : categoryList) {
    CategoryEntryFilter filter = new CategoryEntryFilter();
    FilterPager pager = new FilterPager();
    pager.pageIndex = index;
    pager.pageSize = 500;
    filter.categoryIdEqual = category.id;
    filter.statusEqual = CategoryEntryStatus.ACTIVE;
    CategoryEntryListResponse categoryEntryList = getCategoryEntry(filter, pager);
    if (categoryEntryList.totalCount != 0) {
        System.out.println("categoryEntryList --------->"+categoryEntryList.totalCount);
        tally += categoryEntryLIst.totalCount; //accumulate tally
        for (CategoryEntry entry : categoryEntryList.objects) {
            if (entry != null) {
                categoryEntries.add(entry);
            }
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("All Category entry size ----------->" + tally); // print tally
```

Comment: Thanks. When I tried the above solution its giving me the correct count. I am getting 4551. But I need all CategoryEntry objects to be added into one List. So that I can iterate that list further and do some processing using those.

Comment: your entry != null condition is almost certainly what is preventing you from getting all of the entries added, the question then becomes. is this a bad thing?

Comment: @ Slorello - I have removed the comment and tried. Still the same issue. I found what is the issue. But unable to resolve it. All the categoryEntryList items are getting added to categoryEntries list, but only one list contains 4600+ objects in it. This list is adding only 500 objects to the final list. Because index is not getting increased to 2nd page.

Comment: @Rajyalakshmi S  are you sure you want to be incrementing index outside of your foreach loop? it strikes me that if each page is meant to fit 500 entries that each page you are making has the same index ergo you are overwriting each page as you create it. try moving the index++ into the foreach loop and see what happens